# Attaching PDF file in email

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I need to attach an receipt in the email which has been generated dynamically. I'm unable to attach the pdf file, it denotes me that path is not valid.

Here is my code:

```
public static IRestResponse SendConfirmationEmail(string emailaddress,string subject,string body)
{                
    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = "https://123456";
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", "key-abcdef12345huj");
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
    request.AddParameter("domain", "abc.com", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
    request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
    request.AddParameter("from", "abc <abc@xyz.com>");                
    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("~/users/Receipts/abc-414.pdf");
    request.AddParameter("attachment",attachment);
    request.AddParameter("c", emailaddress);
    request.AddParameter("to", emailaddress);
    request.AddParameter("subject", subject);        
    request.AddParameter("html", body);          
    request.Method = Method.POST;
    return client.Execute(request);               
}
```

Can any one help me out on this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Debug and check if the path is the right one. If not, correct it.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\~ users\Receipts\CEX-41443.pdf'. this is the error ~ symbol to locate its path

Comment: it denotes unrecognized escape sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in this way

```
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/users/Receipts/abc-414.pdf"));
```

use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path on the Web server.

I see that you are sending these parameters in a POST request. Did you check the process of serializing-deserializing? maybe there is something wrong in this step and that parameter is ignored